# How can I get all attributes with PHP xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

Given the following HTML string:

```
<div 
class="example-class" 
data-caption="Example caption" 
data-link="https://www.example.com" 
data-image-url="https://example.com/example.jpg">
</div>
```

How can I use PHP with xpath to output / retrieve an array with all attributes as key / value pairs?

Hoping for output like:

```
Array
(
    [data-caption] => Example caption
    [data-link] => https://www.example.com
    [data-image-url] => https://example.com/example.jpg
)
// etc etc...
```

I know how to get individual attributes, but I'm hoping to do it in one fell swoop. Here's what I currently have:

```
function get_data($html = '') {

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $nodes = $xpath->query('//div/@data-link');

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        var_dump($node);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath, you can use `@*` to reference attributes of any name, for example :

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div/@*');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName ." :  ". $node->nodeValue ."<br>";
}
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/483304)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
class :  example-class
data-caption :  Example caption
data-link :  https://www.example.com
data-image-url :  https://example.com/example.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked well - though in my case I push the items to an array like so: $myarray = array(); $myarray[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want - or at least, give you the basis to proceed.

```
    define('BR','<br />');
    $strhtml='<div 
        class="example-class" 
        data-caption="Example caption" 
        data-link="https://www.example.com" 
        data-image-url="https://example.com/example.jpg">
        </div>';

    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );

    $xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col=$xpath->query('//div');
    if( $col ){
        foreach( $col as $node ) if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) {
            foreach( $node->attributes as $attr ) echo $attr->nodeName.' '.$attr->nodeValue.BR;
        }
    }
    $dom = $col = $xpath = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, whilst it worked, I chose the other poster's answer based on its simplicity and similarity to what I already had.

Comment: Just a question regarding this code: Why the check against node type `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`? Isn't a `DIV` always a DOMElement? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In the above yes, you are correct but if the xpath query was a little different and did not specify the tagname things might be different. I probably just copied this from some working code I had somewhere ~ almost 8yrs ago so I can't remember.