# php xpath query: How to find all <a> in an HTML document that have a title attribute?

Tags: html, xpath, attributes, element

php xpath query: How to find all  in an HTML document that have a title attribute?

For instance, the following is a sample of all the elements that should be matched. These `<a>` elements are also nested inside `<div>`:

`<a href="/subdir/22222" title="The title">`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The query is used in the following code:

```
        $homepage = file_get_contents ("https://somedomain.com");
        
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        @$doc->loadHTML($homepage);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $items = $xpath->query("//a[@title]");
        
        foreach ($items as $node) {
  
              $text = $xpath->evaluate("string(@title)",$node);
              
              $href = $xpath->evaluate("string(@href)",$node);
              
              echo $text;
              echo "<br>";
              echo $href;
             
            }
```

Comment: do you want to find them js or css?

Comment: php xpath: How to find all <a> in an HTML document that have a title attribute

Comment: Would you like to take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199944/how-can-i-get-all-attributes-with-php-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//a[@title]
```

Selects all the `a` elements in document that have an attribute named `title`.

Comment: @65535 No, Matejk00's expression is correct; both in pure xpath and as used in php.

Comment: Works perfectly!